# Handling null field in aggregate using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have come across a scenario where i am summing in my `LINQ` query.

The property could have actually `NULL` in database.

However, when we apply aggregate `i.e. SUM` on same field in collection using LINQ `it calculates/returns 0 for null`

I am avoiding `sum for null` field as following.

```
TotalDays = x.Select(y => y.day.HasValue ? x.Sum(z => z.day) : null).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Is it nice way or could have even better?

Comment: Why do you need to ignore these entries? If you are doing a sum, then the fact that the null value returns 0 doesn't affect the result. If you were counting the entries however ....

Comment: Why now simply - `x.Sum(z => z.day.HasValue ? z.day.Value.Day : 0)`?

Comment: is your propery nullable ? make your propery i.e `TotalDays` nullable i.e `public int?  TotalDays` as by default `int` has `0` value in c#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

Comment: @RahulSingh, yes that is even more simpler and easy to understand, thanks +1 for you.

Comment: @RahulSingh that though can be simplified further to just `x.Sum(z => z.day)`

Comment: @DotNet Dreamer, it is nullable but C# assign 0 when summing two null. See detailed reply below.

Comment: @ Jon Hanna, i don't think so. else it would give same problem i stated in my question. 0 when summing two null values. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null values sum to zero because naturally they can neither add nor subtract to the tally so generally one wants zero in such cases.

Consider:

```
(new int?[]{0, null, 3, 2}).Sum() // result is 5. Other linq providers do similar.
```

Where this can sometimes cause a problem is if you want to note all-null result-sets separately:

```
(new int?[]{null, null}).Sum() // result is 0, but maybe we want to note that there was indeed no values.
```

We could do this with:

```
source.Any(x => x.HasValue) ? source.Sum() : default(int?);
```

Which to bring back to your example would be:

```
int? totalDays = x.Any(y => y.day.HasValue) ? x.Sum(y => y.day) : default(int?);
```

However you might prefer to do:

```
int? totalDays = x.Sum(y => y.day);
if (totalDays == 0 && y.All(y => !y.day.HasValue))
  totalDays = null;
```

Then you only examine the set to see if all values are null in the case of receiving the 0 result (any other result is not possible in this case).

Checking `Any()` first is more efficient when all-null results are more common, and doing `Sum()` first is more efficient when all-null results less common, because in each case you are only doing two operations in the less common case.